# Как создать и загрузить картинку в дельфи

Tags: delphi

Мне необходимо превратить картинку объекта класса TImage в переменную, которую я в случае чего могу загрузить обратно и сделать ее картинкой того же объекта, т.к. он периодически изменяется...

Comment: Приведите хотя бы какой-то [mcve]

Comment: А чем вам объект класса TImage не переменная ?

Comment: при создании прокнрммы у меня не получается сделать дополнительную картинку такого рода... то есть она суцествует, но при попытке к ней обратиться дельфи вылетает

Comment: Приведите минимальный самодостаточный код

Answer (score 3):

Весь код я писать не буду, но рассмотрим случай, когда картинка в BMP, тогда её тип будет `TBitmap`.

```
b : TBimap;
b := TBitmap.Create; 
try 
  b.loadfromfile('a.bmp');
except
   // не забудьте обработчик исключения
end
```

Данные можно хранить в динамических массивах `array of TBitmap`

```
var
  ab : array of TBitmap
begin
    SetLength(ab, 1);
    ab[0] := b;
end;
```

Либо в классе `TList`.

```
List.Add(b);
```

Либо в `TStringList`.

```
var
   Sl :  TStringList; 
begin
   Sl.AddObject('filename', TObject(b));
end;
```

Тут обращение к картинке с использованием типа происходит

```
TBitmap(sl.Objects[0])
```

Этот вариант предпочтительнее так как можно сохранить имя файла.

Можно создать свою структуру и добавлять её в `TList`/`TStringList`

Присвоение картинки

```
Image1.Picture.Graphic := b;
```

У `bitmap` есть методы сохранения в файл и поток, также как и `TPicture`
`(Image1.Picture)`

Можно для сохранения использовать `TMemoryStream`, но это уже тема отдельная.
Таким же образом можно и картинки других типов хранить (jpg, png...)
Нужно не забывать также освобождать память.